# How to merge csv files from nested folders in R

Tags: r, csv, file-io

I have a large collection of csv files that are in different folders and in folders within folders that I need to merge into one file. It would be easy if they were all in one directory but I don't know of a simple way to pull them all out of the different folders. I could combine them one by one but there are A LOT of them.

ex:

```
+ working directory
|
+-- · data.csv
+-- · data2.csv
+-- + NewFolder
    |
    +-- · data3.csv
    +-- + NewFolder2
        |
        +-- · data4.csv
```

I want one file that combines all data csv files

Comment: `list.files()` (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html) should do the job.

Comment: If they were in the same folder would this problem be any different? You're still going to need to read and merge/combine multiple CSV files. You really should be more clear on what's in each file and what you expect the output to be. There are plenty of other questions out there about combining multiple CSV files and I don't see how yours is different.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`dir()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html) with `recursive` set to `TRUE` to list all files in the folder tree, and you can use `pattern` to define a [regular expression](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) to filter the `.csv` files. An example:

```
csv_files <- dir(pattern='.*[.]csv', recursive = T)
```

or even better and simpler (thanks to speendo for his comment):

```
csv_files <- dir(pattern='*.csv$', recursive = T)
```

**The explanation.**

- `pattern='*.csv$`: The `pattern` argument must be a regular expression that filters the file names. This RegEx filters out the file names that end with `.csv`.

  If you want to filter that starts with `data`, you should try a pattern like this: `pattern='^data.*.csv$'`
- `recursive=T`: Forces `dir()` to traverse recursively through all folders below the working directory.

After you get the file list, *and assuming all of them have the same structure* (i.e. all the files have the same columns), you can merge them with `read.csv()` and `rbind()`:

```
for(i in 1:length(csv_files)) {
  if(i == 1)
    df <- read.csv(csv_files[i])
  else
    df <- rdbind(df, read.csv(csv_files[i]))
}
```

---

Ramnath suggests in his comment a faster way to merge the `.csv` files (again, *assuming all of them have the same structure*):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- rbind_all(lapply(csv_files, read_csv))
```

Comment: very good solution (I wonder what is the difference between `dir()` and `list.files()`). Maybe setting `pattern=*.csv$` a good idea...

Comment: @speendo Indeed, that pattern is a better option... editing to include it. Thanks!

Comment: Good solution, although the last loop could take ages, if there are lots of files. Much better (and faster) would be `do.call(rbind,lapply(csv_files,read.csv))`

Comment: I would use `rbind_list` from `dplyr`, which is much faster. So you would write `rbind_list(lapply(csv_files, read.csv))`

Comment: @Ramnath Thank you! I'll edit the post to include your solution (learning something new every day!)

Comment: Actually, it should be `rbind_all` instead of `rbind_list`. Can you make that edit?

Comment: `dplyr::rbind_all` has been replaced by `dplyr::bind_rows`. See more: https://github.com/umatter/pvsR/issues/4

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `dplyr`

```
# get list of files ending in csv in directory root
dir(root, pattern='csv$', recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) %>%
  # read files into data frames
  lapply(FUN = read.csv) %>%
  # bind all data frames into a single data frame
  rbind_all %>%
  # write into a single csv file
  write.csv("all.csv")
```

Comment: WOW! that `%>%` operator is new to me (and I'm sure I'm not the only one surprised)!

Comment: The pipe operator (`%>%`) is a relatively new development in R, and leads to highly readable code.

Comment: The pipe was also new to me. Looks like it's part of the [magrittr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html)-Package.

Answer (score 0):

This solution has the assumption that all `*.csv` files have the same structure.

(Untested)

```
fileList <- list.files(
  pattern="*.csv$",
  recursive=TRUE,
  full.name=TRUE,
  )

completeCSV <- data.frame()


for(file in fileList) {
  print(file) # for debug: print current file
  if (nrow(completeCSV) == 0) {
    completeCSV <- read.csv(file)
  } else {
    curDF <- read.csv(file) # could also be read.csv2()
    rbind(completeCSV, curDF)
  }
}

write.csv(completeCSV) # could also be write.csv2()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Base R solution.

```
files <- list.files(path = ".",pattern = "*.csv",recursive = TRUE)

write.csv(do.call(rbind,lapply(files, read.csv)), "combined_data.csv")
```