# Extract the paths to all .csvs in a nested directory and read them in as a single data frame

Tags: r, csv

Structure: *data* folder and 3 subject folders (*p01*, *p02*, *p03*).

I am faced with a situation where, say, *p01* may require drilling down through 5 subdirectories to obtain the `.csv` whereas *p02* may have no further subdirectories.

Is there an any easy way to simply extract the paths to all .csvs in a directory (*data*) and read them in as a single data frame?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge csv files from nested folders in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181122/how-to-merge-csv-files-from-nested-folders-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
# Get paths/names of all csv files in the directory (including files in any subdirectories)
files = list.files(pattern="csv$", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)

# Read the files into a list of data frames
df.list = lapply(files, read.csv)

# Combine all the data frames into a single data frame
df = do.call(rbind, df.list)
```

I'm assuming here that all the files have the same column names.

Comment: I didn't test the code, but I would have thought that either `lapply` or `sapply` would work. I prefer `sapply` because it uses the file names as the list element names, whereas `lapply` just uses consecutive numbers. I've changed to `lapply` in the answer.

Comment: Works very well now. Thanks for the help.